# how to verify xlsx file and DB

Tags: java, excel

I am uploading an excel file which contains DB table. Then I insert those records into the DB table. What are the ways to verify whether all of them uploaded perfectly?

**These are the approaches I tried**

1. I already test the counts of excel file vs insert.
2. download the DB table as Excel and compare that excel with uploaded excel.

What are the other way to test?

Comment: How you are processing your excel file ? in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file and create a file checksum and thus generate a hex value, then read the DB data create a hex and validate against the generated hex value.